# Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop, excel-interop

Here I'm opening excel and writing to excel sheet. I'm changing my windows application to asp website and seen this error. I have added all the references and libraries. Don't know what I am missing here.

Getting error as mentioned below. Please help me.

```
    Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
    excel.Visible = false; // to hide the processing 
    Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Add();
    Excel.Worksheet sh = wb.Sheets.Add(); // Error at wb


    sh.Name = "Links";

    for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        sh.Cells[i.ToString(), "A"].Value2 = list[i]; //Error at .Value2

    }
```

Comment: Are you missing a cast?  Yes.  Never, *never* run Excel on a web server.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you have to create a new Worksheet with `Sheets` array by providing `WorkSheet` Name.
and also please Cast The Newly Created `WorkSheet`.

**Replace this :**

```
Excel.Worksheet sh = wb.Sheets.Add();
```

**with following**

```
 Excel.Worksheet sh  = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Sheets["Sheet1"];
```

Answer (score 1):

To resolve your second error,

//Error at .Value2

1. Go to project properties. (Click Project in Menu, Click properties)
2. Set the Target Framework as .NET Framework 4
3. This should resolve your .Value2 error.